# What is the /etc/apt/sources.list file supposed to look like for 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, apt, software-sources

I accidentally deleted `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Now `apt-get update` doesn't quite get as much good stuff as it's supposed to. Please, somebody, paste contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` so that I can copy-&-paste it back.

I'm on Kubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm running Kubuntu 10.10 as well, this comes from my `sources.list`. You should change `nl.archive.ubuntu.com` to your local mirror.

```
# deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 10.10 _Maverick Meerkat_ - Release amd64 (20101007)]/ maverick main restricted

# deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 10.10 _Maverick Meerkat_ - Release amd64 (20101007)]/ maverick main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted
deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted
deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick universe
deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick universe
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe
deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick multiverse
deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick multiverse
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates multiverse
deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main
#deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
```

Comment: If you have a LiveCD / LiveUSB, you can start Kubuntu from it in Live mode and copy the file over. Just another safe option.

Answer (score 5):

**[Ubuntu Sources List Generator](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/)**

To use the Ubuntu Sources List Generator, all you have to do is select the applications for which you want to generate a sources.list, then click the "Generate" button at the bottom, then open your sources.list file with admin rights:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and paste the generated repositories, then do:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Uhm, where do you find that Ubuntu Sources List generator and where do you select the applications?

Comment: @Septagram Click the link in the answer above that says "Ubuntu Sources List Generator".